# cs50 pset4 recover.c need advice

Tags: c, cs50

I could use some guidance on this pset from cs50.  Below is the code i have so far.  I am stuck at this point where i have no idea how to proceed.  When i run the program it does output 16 jpg files but i cannot view them so something must be wrong. Any tips are welcome.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int main(void)
{               
// create buffer to store in
unsigned char buffer[512];

// array for filename is 8 for "000.jpg"
char jpgName[8];

// declaring counter for amount of jpegs
int jpgcounter = 0;

// open memory card file
FILE* inptr = fopen("card.raw", "r");
FILE* outptr = NULL;

if (inptr == NULL)
{
    printf("Could not open %s.\n", "card.raw");
    return 1;
}   

    // repeat until end of card 
    while(fread(buffer, sizeof(buffer), 1, inptr) == 1)
    {                                   

        // find beginning of jpg
        if(buffer[0] == 0xff && buffer[1] == 0xd8 && buffer[2] == 0xff && (buffer[3] == 0xe0 || buffer[3] == 0xe1))
        {   
            // if allready a outptr file is open close it
            if (outptr != NULL)
            {
                    fclose(outptr);
            }

            // create filename for jpegs
            sprintf(jpgName,"%03d.jpg", jpgcounter);

            // open a new file with name defined by sprintf
            FILE* outptr = fopen(jpgName, "w");                             

            // write into the outfile from buffer
            fwrite(&buffer, sizeof(buffer), 1, outptr);

            // increment counter for jpegs
            jpgcounter++;
           }                                    
    }
    fclose(inptr);
    return 0;   
}
```

Comment: Was it your intent to only write every *other* 512-bytes? because that is what this does. If not intended, you have an extraneous `fread` in your loop. A google search of "cs50 pset4 recover" yields a surprising number of *correct* implementations, for reference, fyi.

Comment: you have one read in while, why you have another one directly after it? maybe you wanna better describe what the task is. also open files in binary mode?

Comment: the task at hand was to find 16 jpegs in card.raw file.  And copy them into seperate files.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I understood your task correctly, you want something like this-please see below.
Hint: what are you planning to do if it is not beginning of jpg file?

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int main(void)
{               

unsigned char buffer[512] = {0};
char jpgName[8] = {0};
int jpgcounter = 0;
FILE* outptr = NULL;

// open memory card file
FILE* inptr = fopen("card.raw", "rb");
if (inptr == NULL)
{
    printf("Could not open %s.\n", "card.raw");
    return 1;
}   

// Start reading    
while(fread(buffer, sizeof(buffer), 1, inptr) == 1)
{                                   

        // Find beginning of jpg
        if(buffer[0] == 0xff && buffer[1] == 0xd8 && buffer[2] == 0xff && (buffer[3] == 0xe0 || buffer[3] == 0xe1))
        {   
            if(NULL!=outptr)                   
            {
              fclose(outptr);
              outptr=NULL;
            }

            // Create filename for jpegs
            sprintf(jpgName,"%03d.jpg", jpgcounter);

            // Open a new file with name defined by sprintf
            outptr = fopen(jpgName, "wb");         
            if (NULL == outptr)
            {
              printf("Could not open %s.\n", jpgName);
              return 1;
            }                     

            // Write into the outfile from buffer
            fwrite(buffer, sizeof(buffer), 1, outptr);

            // Increment counter for jpegs
            jpgcounter++;
         }
          else 
         {
             // Continue writing to old file if it is not beginning of file
             if(NULL!=outptr)
                fwrite(buffer, sizeof(buffer), 1, outptr);                              
         }   
    }

    if(NULL!=outptr)
      fclose(outptr);
    if(NULL!=inptr)
      fclose(inptr);

    return 0;   
}
```

Comment: Thank you giorgi, it workes now.  But i still have some questions.  What does "wb" mean in fopen?  I only know of w for write and r for read.

Comment: @VerpoortenNick: b means binary. You want to open jpgs in binary mode. But I am not sure maybe it is OS dependant whether you need to specify b or not, you might want to look it up.

Answer (score 0):

This can't work:

```
while(fread(buffer, sizeof(buffer), 1, inptr) == 1)
{                                   

    // read 512 bytes from inptr and store them in buffer
    fread(&buffer, sizeof(buffer) , 1, inptr);
```

as you use `fread` twice and the data read by the first get overwritten by the second. It looks as if this loses the first 512 bytes of every kB in the original file.

You should get further if you delete the second fread().

Comment: Thank you for pointing that out.  I have removed the second fread but i still cannot view the jpg files.

Comment: @VerpoortenNick It's hard to tell without knowledge of the input format. Is your input format really a sequence of jpeg files, each of which is exactly 512 bytes long?

Comment: Yes this is from the pset: And so I’ve gone ahead and created a "forensic image" of the card, storing its contents, byte after byte, in a file called card.raw. So that you don’t waste time iterating over millions of 0s unnecessarily, I’ve only imaged the first few megabytes of the CF card. But you should ultimately find that the image contains 16 JPEGs